# How to remove string between two characters and before the first occurrence using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to remove the string between ":" and the first "|" using sed.

input:
`|abc:1.2.3|def|`

output from sed:
`|abc|def|`

I managed to come up with sed `'s|\(:\)[^|]*|\1|'`, but this sed command does not remove the first character (":"). How can I modify this command to also remove the colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to group `:` in your pattern and use it in substitution.

You should keep it simple:

```sh
s='|abc:1.2.3|def|'
sed 's/:[^|]*//' <<< "$s"

|abc|def|
```

`:` matches a colon and `[^|]*` matches 0 or more non-pipe characters

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` you could try following `awk` program.

```
awk 'match($0,/:[^|]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function of `awk`, where matching from `:` to till first occurrence of `|` here. So what `match` function does is, whenever a regex is matched in it, it will SET values for its OOTB variables named `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, so based on that we are printing sub-string to neglect matched part and print everything else as per required output in question.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `FPAT` option in GNU `awk`, try following, written and tested with your shown samples only.

```
awk -v FPAT=':[^|]*' '{print $1,$2}'  Input_file
```